# Regex to only allow you to type "." after the first "0" then any number after in a calculator app

Tags: javascript, regex, calculator

I'm trying to use a regex replace to not allow you to input any other digit other than a decimal after you first input a zero. For a calculator app. So that the display can't look like 000003 and instead would just stay on 0 until you type 3.

Comment: Where is your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used this in the past as a quick fix and worked for me.

`input= input.replace(/^0*/g,"0").replace(/^0*(\d)/g, "$1");`

replace all leading 0s with only one '0' but then delete that one '0' if it is followed by a digit.

Also to ensure only 1 dot is entered replace multiple dots with 1 dot:

`input = input.replace(/\.+/g, ".");`

Comment: That solved the problem of multiple zeros at the start. Now I'm trying to use regex to have it display "0." when you type "." instead of just "." Here's what I have so far `${number.replace(/^0+/, "") + num}`

Answer (score 0):

Will this work :-)

```
input= input.replace(/^0*/g,"0").replace(/^0*(\d)/g, "$1").replace(/^(\.)/g,".0").replace(/\.+/g, ".");
```